# Tag word in HTML with a variable web address from python?

Tags: python, html

I want to make a word in HTML clickable and then send the user to a website. But this specific website must be variable.
I run the logic in python, read in the HTML in there and refer the variable.

My Code in HTML looks like this. I calculate the deal_href in python. I read in the HTML in python and send a mail with this html.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
     <body>
        <p>Hallo, <br> <br>
           how is it going?.<br>
           Click <a href="{deal_href}">here</a> please.<br>
           <br>

        </p>
      </body>
</html>
```

My Python Code:

```
msg = codecs.open(r'"my Path"','r','utf-8').read()
msg = html2text.html2text(msg.format(**locals()))
sendMail(msg)
```

I excpected to get the email with the clickable "here" and the specific link. But I get: Click here and the link redirects to my local files.

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Please provide ur python code

Comment: Hi, yes! I did that now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not a lean solution but it works.

Some explanation about the solution:

- open(file,w+) to create a html file.
- write to add line by line.
- \n to jump line.
- with name_variable = "nico", f.write("hello {}".format(name_variable)) for print "hello nico"

```py
deal_href = "example"

f= open("webcode.html","w+")
f.write("<html>\n")
f.write("    <head></head>\n")
f.write("     <body>\n")
f.write("        <p>Hallo, <br> <br>\n")
f.write("           how is it going?.<br>\n")
f.write("           Click <a href={}>here</a> please.<br>\n".format(deal_href))
f.write("           <br>\n")
f.write("        </p>\n")
f.write("      </body>\n")
f.write("</html>")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I guess this is not really clean and could lead to more complexitiy with increasing size of html doc... I guess there could be a more easier way!

Comment: Yes, I think the same. The point is that I'm a novel developer, so this is my best try. I hope some people could help in a better way.